# Test convergence of $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \sin \left( n \pi + \frac{1}{\log{n}} \right) $

Tags: calculus

I have doing this with taylor series but fail. Can anyone give a hints to test the convergence of

$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \sin \left( n \pi + \frac{1}{\log{n}} \right) $$

Comment: Hint: $\sin(n\pi + a_n) = (-1)^n \sin a_n$.

Comment: You have $\sin\left(n\pi +\frac{1}{\log n}\right)=\sin\left(n\pi\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)+\cos(n\pi)\sin\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)=(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)$. Now, use Leibniz.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\sin\left(n\pi+\frac1{\ln n}\right)=(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac1{\ln n}\right)$$
and use the Leibniz criterion.

Comment: to be a little bit picky, u also need to show that the second expression indeed goes to zero for $n \rightarrow \infty$